# Jquery Trigger is firing the wrong table column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically generated table with many checkboxes with same name and click event. I am using an ALL checkbox in every column which will check all the checkbox in that column .
The code is 
***dynamically generated checkboxes

```
    if (discountProductGroupBuyer != null)
    {
    sb.Append("<td><input name=productGroupWiseCustomer id='" + "GetProduct" + customerGroup + "' type=checkbox checked=true value=mlb onclick=GetProduct('" + customerGroup + "') ></td>");
    }
```

****onclick of generated checkboxes

```
   function GetProduct(ids) {
    debugger;
   var str = ids;
   var temp = [];
   temp.length = 0;
   temp = str.toString().split('-');

var addOrDelete = ""; 
var checkboxid = "#GetProduct" + ids;
if ($(checkboxid).is(":checked")) {
    addOrDelete = true;
    var flag = 0;
    $.grep(ProductGroupID, function (item, idx) {
        if (item.DiscountTypeId == temp[0] && item.BuyerId == temp[1] && item.ProductGroupId == temp[2]) {
            //ProductGroupID.splice(idx, 1);
            item.DiscountTypeId = temp[0];
            item.BuyerId = temp[1];
            item.ProductGroupId = temp[2];
            item.AddOrDelete = addOrDelete;
            flag = 1;
        }
    });
    if (flag == 0) {
        ProductGroupID.push({
            DiscountTypeId:temp[0],
            BuyerId:temp[1],
            ProductGroupId:temp[2],
            AddOrDelete:addOrDelete
        });
    }
}
else {
    addOrDelete = false;
    flag = 0;
    $.grep(ProductGroupID, function(item, idx) {
        if (item.DiscountTypeId == temp[0] && item.BuyerId == temp[1] && item.ProductGroupId == temp[2]) {
            //ProductGroupID.splice(idx, 1);
            item.DiscountTypeId = temp[0];
            item.BuyerId = temp[1];
            item.ProductGroupId = temp[2];
            item.AddOrDelete = addOrDelete;
            flag = 1;
        }
    });
    if (flag == 0) {
        ProductGroupID.push({
            DiscountTypeId:temp[0],
            BuyerId:temp[1],
            ProductGroupId:temp[2],
            AddOrDelete:addOrDelete
        });
    }
}
```

}

*** Check all code

```
$(document).on("click", "#chkAll", function () {

    var cbody = $(this),
    theader = cbody.parent(),
    column = theader.index() + 1;
    $("#tbody td:nth-child(" + column + ") input").prop("checked", this.checked);

});
```

Which seems to work and its checking all the checkbox in that specific column
like below image.

[image]

But the problem arise after adding a trigger event. Let me explain

I have also a trigger click event which will be fired by clicking that all checkbox for that specific column only. The problem is when I click the `#chkAll` checkbox its not triggering that specific column but triggering for the other column checkbox.

```
$(document).on("click", "#chkAll", function () {

     var cbody = $(this),
     theader = cbody.parent(),
     column = theader.index() + 1;
     $("#tbody td:nth-child(" + column + ") input").prop("checked", this.checked);
     $("input:checkbox[name='productGroupWiseCustomer']").trigger('click');      

});
```

What I am trying to achieve that by clicking individual column's #chkAll  checkbox it will trigger only the checkboxes under that column only.Help Needed .Thanks for help

I also added a photo.[image]

Comment: Clearly you have several checkboxes with the name `productGroupWiseCustomer`, and you're targeting all of them. What you need to do is traverse the DOM starting with `this`, and then find only the checkbox you want to trigger. We can't do it for you, as we have no idea what your markup looks like, making it impossible to answer the question!

Comment: @adeneo     look the first image i am able to check that specific first column checkboxes .What i need to do  fire trigger for  only those checkboxs under that specific column only  thats it

Comment: As I can select all the checkboxes in that specific column so the should be a way to trigger only those checkboxes only but i am unable to add the condition  @adeneo

Comment: @AsifuzzamanRedoy is it possible to generate mark up in such way that each checkbox will have different id . Like under Noodles column it would noo1 , noo2 , Detergent column det1 , det2 . would that make it simple to trigger correct checkbox ?

Comment: I am Asking if this is possible to fire specific column checkboxes ???And Yes  I have different id for every checkboxes which i generated from backend.All I need to fire only those which are checked .this is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you not only want to (un)check the whole column of checkboxes, you also want the checkboxes that change because of this action, to have their event handlers executed. That second requirement is not happening when using `prop`. You could chain a call to `trigger`, but be aware that this will toggle the check *again*.

The solution is to select only those checkboxes in the column whose checkbox needs to toggle (which might not be all of them), and then to call `.trigger("click")` on those. This will both change their checked status *and* call the corresponding event handlers.

Here is how you could do it:

```
$("#tbody td:nth-child(" + column + ") input"
             + (this.checked ? ":not(:checked)" : ":checked").trigger('click');
```

Here is a working fiddle:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".chkAll", function () {
    var cbody = $(this),
        theader = cbody.parent(),
        column = theader.index() + 1;
    $("#tbody td:nth-child(" + column + ") input"
             + (this.checked ? ":not(:checked)" : ":checked")).trigger('click');
});

// Dummy click handler just to give visual clue that it gets called
function GetProduct(input) {
    $(input).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
}
```

```css
th { background-color: silver }
td { text-align: center }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Noodles<br><input class="chkAll" type="checkbox"></th>
<th>Detergent<br><input class="chkAll" type="checkbox"></th>
<th>Chocolate<br><input class="chkAll" type="checkbox"></th>
</tr>
<tbody id="tbody">
<tr>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
The fickering of the checkboxes is intentional: it is evidence of the click handlers being invoked.
```

#### Calling the event handler for all checkboxes

Checkboxes that do not change state should not need to get their click event handler caller. Since you insist in comments on this point, and I failed to convince you that this is conceptually wrong, you could use `.triggerHandler` (instead of `.trigger`) to call the event handler on all checkboxes of the clicked column -- but without any real click being simulated.

Again, this is not best practice:

```
$("#tbody td:nth-child(" + column + ") input").prop("checked", this.checked))
    .each(function() {
        $(this).triggerHandler('click');
    });
```

Here is a working fiddle:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".chkAll", function () {
    var cbody = $(this),
        theader = cbody.parent(),
        column = theader.index() + 1;
    $("#tbody td:nth-child(" + column + ") input").prop("checked", this.checked)
        .each(function() {
            $(this).triggerHandler('click');
        });
});

// Dummy click handler just to give visual clue that it gets called
function GetProduct(input) {
    $(input).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
}
```

```css
th { background-color: silver }
td { text-align: center }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>Noodles<br><input class="chkAll" type="checkbox"></th>
<th>Detergent<br><input class="chkAll" type="checkbox"></th>
<th>Chocolate<br><input class="chkAll" type="checkbox"></th>
</tr>
<tbody id="tbody">
<tr>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
<td><input name="productGroupWiseCustomer" type="checkbox" onclick="GetProduct(this)"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
The fickering of the checkboxes is intentional: it is evidence of the click handlers being invoked.
```

Comment: its selecting the whole column but not firing the trigger of click event !  should i add the name of the checkbox ???? When i individually click them the trigger works . but when select all its not working

Comment: Make sure you do this but also remove your `.prop("checked")` calls. Triggering click is causing your checkboxes to be clicked, thus changing the state. In your original post this explains why the other columns  show up clicked... You check all the ones you need but then you trigger click on everything thus toggling the checked state. This solution above should work so long as you don't set the checked property yourself

Comment: i used the same code its checking the checkboxes but not firing the click event of the corresponding checkboxes .what should i do ???? please help needed. , whithout using the name of the checkboxes its not working at all  @pinkfloydx33

Comment: Maybe you should update your original post to include your markup (html) as well as your full js (as it pertains to the issue) which would include the click handlers for the individual checkboxes that you claim to not be working . We aren't mind readers, could be something totally different going on but we're mostly left to guess. This answer should work fine, the fact you say it's not leads me to believe there's something you're not showing us

Comment: i added the mark up and also   if I Use this code                                                                   $("#tbody td:nth-child(" + column + ") input:checkbox[name='productGroupWiseCustomer']").prop("checked", this.checked).trigger('click');                                                                                        its works but checkboxes  becomes unchecked but the trigger works  @pinkfloydx33

Comment: Hello @pinkfloydx33 I think its  working but  when i checked and then unchecked it again then it works the trigger fired . . . could  you help why me its fiering  after unchecked it /after second click???  is there any brackets or something missig ??? because of this its working on not checked.

Comment: The trigger is only happening for when the checkbox *changes* state. So a checkbox that is already checked in a column that you are checking as a whole will not get the click event, while checkboxes that were cleared before you did this will get their click handler run.

Comment: So In this case What should i do Sir ??? Where should i change ? @trincot

Comment: I don't understand what you want to change? There should be no reason to call a click handler on a checkbox when its state has not changed. Are you by any chance clearing `ProductGroupID` when you handle the column click? If so, then that is wrong. Don't touch your data there. Let all be done in the individual checkboxes' click handlers (with this code).

Comment: i want to trigger the checkbox onclick  event . when i click the all checkbox thats it . . If i am clicking every checkbox once at a time then the trigger works .but when i want to select all the the trigger doesnt work . . But by your code it works after unchecked again the checkbox i mean after second click . . So i am making mistakes between these issues.For Individually its working but i also need to select all at a time   Sir @trincot

Comment: Please understand that clicking each checkbox separately is not the same thing as wanting the whole column to have its checkboxes set to one and the same state, even if some already had that state. I can only repeat what I wrote above. Please try to understand why conceptually it is wrong to expect a click event on a checkbox that already had the desired state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148728/discussion-between-asifuzzaman-redoy-and-trincot).

Comment: I have added a fiddle to prove it works (also on the first click). I added an alternative that calls the event handlers also for checkboxes that do not change because of the column click, again with a fiddle. If this does not work for you, there must be something responsible for that on your page. Provide a working fiddle so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: hello Sir Thanks for your fiddle .As you see only the  first checkbox   in each column is firing the animate(fickering) method .I need to fire all at once or at the same time  How could i do that ???

Comment: I am using chrome . I mean they individually fire the animate  method .but when i click chkall only the first one fires and animate  and it is same for all the column .

Comment: i want that all checkbox will animate when i will click chkAll. .   I hope u understand!!!

Comment: I misunderstood: I was looking at my first fiddle. I fixed the second fiddle. But be reminded that that solution is not best practice. If the first one does not work for you, then you some other issues in your code.

Comment: Thank  you very much sir The second one somehow worked for me .I know its not good practice but  it seems that i have no other ways .Very much grateful to you

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/d9x95q2q/1/

```js
$(document).on("click", ".checkAll", function () {
     var cbody = $(this);
     var theader = cbody.parent();
     var column = theader.index() + 1;
   $('.col' + column ).prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
      col 1 <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" />
    </th>
    <th>
      col 2 <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" />
    </th>
    <th>
      col 3 <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" />
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="col1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="col2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="col3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="col1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="col2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="col3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="col1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="col2" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="col3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks your click triggers next column.
Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#chkAll", function () {

   var cbody = $(this),
   theader = cbody.parent(),

   // index already makes the +1 for you
   column = theader.index();

   var td_set = $("#tbody td:nth-child(" + column + ") input");
   td_set.prop("checked", this.checked);

   td_set.trigger('click');      
});
```

The sentence `$("input:checkbox[name='productGroupWiseCustomer']").trigger('click');` fires a new click in your table and check, still, the next column.

**Update**
Now the code triggers click for every checkbox that is set as checked.

Comment: i must add the trigger event to fire the checked checkboxes

Comment: ok, so any checkbox in the current column must fire...I edit the answer

Comment: nope its not firing the checkboxes click event !!! that means the trigger is not working

Comment: should i use the name of the checkboxses.When i individually click them the trigger works . but when select all its not working.

Comment: still no change . You know i  have to use the name  and only for those checkbox that are being checked. thats how it works but i cant seperate the checked ones